# Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515

Tags: dll, cmd, visual-studio-2015, qgis

I am trying to build QGIS open source application in Windows. I used this link for it -> [link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL)

But I am getting the error "Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515". I think it is about some missing dlls. Also, the error is related(opinion) about crssync.exe because building fails after running that exe file. Additionally, when i tried debug start new instace from Visual studio 2015 it shows me (on console) not loaded 3 dlls but two of them are system one is about OSGeo4W. Then shows a missing dll error on the screen about gdal301.dll and proj_6_3.dll.

I tried to execute crsyync.exe directly. It gave me lots of dll missing error two of them is same with above. I add their locations on the path variable then tried again, problems solved no errors. However when i builded again it gave me same error. When i clicked the error it shows me "Microsoft.CppCommon.targets" file.

```
 <CustomBuild
  Sources                     ="@(CustomBuild)"
  BuildSuffix                 ="$(_BuildSuffix)"

  TrackerLogDirectory         ="%(CustomBuild.TrackerLogDirectory)"
  MinimalRebuildFromTracking  ="%(CustomBuild.MinimalRebuildFromTracking)"

  TLogReadFiles               ="@(CustomBuildTLogReadFiles)"
  TLogWriteFiles              ="@(CustomBuildTLogWriteFiles)"
  TrackFileAccess             ="$(TrackFileAccess)"
  ToolArchitecture            ="$(CustomBuildToolArchitecture)"
  TrackerFrameworkPath        ="$(CustomBuildTrackerFrameworkPath)"
  TrackerSdkPath              ="$(CustomBuildTrackerSdkPath)"

  AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes  ="%(CustomBuild.AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes)"
  >
</CustomBuild>
```

Comment: -1073741515 = 0xC0000135 = The code execution cannot proceed because %hs was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. = WinError 0x7e = The specified module could not be found. https://pastebin.com/dX5mgw81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is it can not find the gdal301.dll and proj_6_3.dll in the apps folder. Because it looks at the OSGeo4W\bin folder. When i copied and pasted them into that folder it worked and run the qgis.